# What's the short cut for fg in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

`ctrl-z` is the short cut for `bg`,what's for `fg`?

Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>crtl+z</kbd> sends the suspend signal (SIGTSTP). It doesn't place the process in the background.

Comment: it works as `bg` while in `vim`,so I want another short cut to go back to vim instead of typing `fg`..

Comment: Nope, wrong again. Vim is being suspended; that is not the same as running in the background. A suspended job is just that, one that isn't running. `bg` runs the job, but stdin and stdout are no longer attached to the console. `fg` attaches a background or suspended job to the console again.

Comment: is there a short cut to attach a suspended job to the console again?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, though various distributions tend to do whatever they please.

Comment: +1 to @ChrisS for this observation.  Some distributions/versions of terminal applications will also allow the end user to set their own custom keyboard commands through a GUI or setting menu.  For example Terminal.app on OS X will allow some customization under `Terminal->Preferences->Keyboard`.

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own in $HOME/.inputrc...

```
# ALT+Z
"\M-z": "fg\n"
```

...or by adding `bind -x`'s to your .profile/.bashrc.

```
bind -x '"\M-z"':"fg" # ALT+Z
```

For more information, see the READLINE section of the bash manpage.

Comment: just tried,seems not working.

Comment: Which method did you try?
Did you reload the relevant files? (e.g., logging out/back in; starting a new shell; running `. .bashrc` or `. .profile`; or pressing `CTRL+x CTRL+r` for `.inputrc` if default keybindings haven't been changed)
If so, do you get any errors?

Answer (score 5):

The goal is, I suppose, to exit `vim`, do some shell stuff and reenter `vim` as fast as possible. I got quite fast by using <kbd>crtl+z</kbd> to exit `vim` and <kbd>crtl+z</kbd> again to reenter.

Exit works well without further ado.

To make the reentry work I *undef*ed the standard <kbd>crtl+z</kbd> behaviour (`susp`) and mapped it to `fg` followed by the Enter key (`\015`).

These are the relevant lines from my `.bashrc`.

```
stty susp undef
bind '"\C-z":"fg\015"'
```

Works like a charm on OS X 10.10 and Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS. Probably should work on other Unices, too.

See also this [Github Repo](https://github.com/tybenz/ctrl-z) for a nice looking solution using iTerm2 and these [vim productivity hints](http://sheerun.net/2014/03/21/how-to-boost-your-vim-productivity/) for a native `zsh` implementation (hint VII) and other general awesomeness.

Comment: Wait until you discover `:!`...

Comment: Yeah, I know about `:!`. It's just better suited to one off commands and not for longer sessions in the shell. Of course, one could also use a `tmux` split and a `vim` session side by side...

Comment: And I have multiple Konsoles open. There's more than one way...

Comment: So I didn´t undef susp, and did `bind -x '"\C-a":"fg"'` and this works great. ctrl-a is now 'anti-ctrl-z', so I can quickly switch between terminal and vim, and only one arrow up to repeat last command to test the updated script or code.